Help in debugging corrupt registers in a register array in a digital ASIC
I have a question regarding digital ASIC design. I have recently received a digital ASIC after fabrication implemented in 65nm LP CMOS process. In the ASIC, I have declared a large register bank (a 1488-depth, 12-bits register array = 2.232KB). Since this is the only one large memory I have, I decided to use a register array instead of using a memory standard cell from the vendor library. During testing of the ASIC, I find the following issue:
In some of the registers in the register array, one of the bits are always tied to 0 or always tied to 1. This in a sense, corrupts that whole register in the array. And I am wondering what could be the possible reason for this. I have multiple samples of the ASIC, and in all the same registers are 'corrupt'.
For reference, my final layout is done for CLK period of 50ns (20MHz) and my operating CLK is 390ns (2.56MHz). There is no timing violation issue since the slack after final place and route is exactly 0 for the complete digital design.
Can anyone in the community please help me figure out what could possibly be the reason for such an issue, or how do I think about this problem that a fabricated ASIC's memory cells can be corrupted?
I have already cross-checked the synthesis and layout scripts, they are completely fine (also they have been used previously for other designs that worked perfectly).
Here is the code of the register array:
module SPSRAM #(
    parameter ADDRESS_WIDTH = 11,    // Log2(WORD_DEPTH)
    parameter WORD_DEPTH = 1488,
    parameter WORD_WIDTH = 12
)(
    input wire CLK,  // clock
    input wire CEB,  // active low chip-enable
    input wire WEB,  // active low write-enable
    input wire [ADDRESS_WIDTH-1:0] A,  // address
    input wire [WORD_WIDTH-1:0] D,     // data in
    output wire [WORD_WIDTH-1:0] Q     // data out
);

    // Memory array
    reg [WORD_WIDTH-1:0] mem [0:WORD_DEPTH-1];
    
    assign Q = (!CEB && WEB) ? mem[A] : {WORD_WIDTH{1'b0}};  // Read operation

    // Process for write operation
    always @(posedge CLK) begin
        if (!CEB && !WEB) begin
                mem[A] <= D;
        end
    end

endmodule

